# Woocommerce Bookings resources grouping

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I have a bookable product named 'Futsal' with Resources added as Arena (5-aside and 7 aside).

If someone books 7-aside for a particular time, two 5-aside  of respective time should not be available.

I'm using [Woocommerce Bookings](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-extensions/woocommerce-bookings/) plugin